# Is $T : V → V$ not an isomorphism if T doesn't have eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let$ T: V→V $ be a linear transformation $$$$**Prove/Disprove**:
  If T is not an isomorphism, then T has no eigenvalues. $$$$I think that by proving that if T has eigenvalues then we can prove that T is inverse thus proving it is isomorphism. However I'm not sure how to continue. What do you think of this way of proof?

Comment: Try $T(x,y) = (x,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Take $Tx=0$ for all $x \in V$. Clearly not an isomorphism, yet all non-zero vectors are eigenvectors.

Comment: It seems your title is the converse of your Prove/Disprove.  "If P, then Q" is not equivalent to "P, if Q".

Answer (score 1):

Here, you assume the statement is true. Thats why you prove it via contrapositive. But however it is false.

Any $n \times n$ matrix can be viewed as a linear transformation from $\Bbb F^n$ to $\Bbb F^n$. So in particular, take $T$ to be any nilpotent matrix, which is not invertible, but has eigenvalues, namely all of zeros!

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is no isomorphism its kernel is non-trivial, hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.